# How can I call the destructor on a non-trivially-copyable/destructable type stored in an std::vector<char>?

Tags: c++

The following code creates a bunch of objects and then `std::copy`s them into an `std::vector<char>`.

I can successfully reinterpret pointers into the `std::vector<char>` in order to "retrieve" the original object. But how do I then delete the original object to ensure there's no memory leaks?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

class ComplexType
{
public:

    constexpr static std::size_t numItems = 200;

    ComplexType()
    :
        dynamic(new int[numItems])
    {
        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < numItems; ++i)
        {
            dynamic[i] = i;
        }
    }

    ComplexType(const ComplexType& c)
    :
        dynamic(new int[numItems])
    {
        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < numItems; ++i)
            dynamic[i] = c.dynamic[i];
    }

    ~ComplexType()
    {
        delete[] dynamic;
    }

    void Print()
    {
        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < numItems; ++i)
        {
            std::cout << dynamic[i] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    int* dynamic;
};

struct Data
{
    std::vector<int> a;
    float b;
    ComplexType c;
};

int a = 0;
float b = 0;

Data CreateMoreData()
{
    Data data;

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
        data.a.push_back(++a*i);

    data.b = b;

    b += .01f;

    return data;
}

int main()
{
    using CharArray = std::vector<char>;

    const int numItems = 10;

    CharArray charArray;

    std::vector<Data> someData;

    for(int i = 0; i < numItems; ++i)
        someData.push_back(CreateMoreData());

    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < someData.size(); ++i)
    {
        CharArray::size_type currentSize = charArray.size();
        CharArray::size_type newSize = currentSize + sizeof(Data);
        charArray.resize(newSize);

        Data* startPtr = &someData[i];
        Data* endPtr = startPtr+1;
        std::copy(startPtr, endPtr, reinterpret_cast<Data*>(&charArray[currentSize]));
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < numItems; ++i)
    {
        Data* data = reinterpret_cast<Data*>(&charArray[i*sizeof(Data)]);

        for(std::size_t j = 0; j < data->a.size(); ++j)
            std::cout << data->a[j] << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;

        std::cout << data->b << std::endl;

        data->c.Print();

        /* how do I now ensure that the original Data struct is deleted correctly ?*/
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have tried:

```
Data rData;
Data* startPtr = reinterpret_cast<Data*>(&charArray[i*sizeof(Data)]);
std::copy(startPtr, startPtr + 1, &rData);
```

and I've tried:

```
Data* rData;
Data* startPtr = reinterpret_cast<Data*>(&charArray[i*sizeof(Data)]);
std::copy(startPtr, startPtr + 1, rData);
delete rData;
```

I've also tried:

```
Data* rData;
Data* startPtr = reinterpret_cast<Data*>(&charArray[i*sizeof(Data)]);
std::copy(startPtr, startPtr + 1, rData);
rData->~Data();
```

Comment: Start over. in particular research [*"placement new"*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) in any off/on-line C++ reference. It will cover how to both properly construct and destroy objects in pre-existing memory regions. It is literally what the language feature was designed for, and it sounds like what you're seeking.